# Is it fine without 'in'?

Tags: prepositions

The original sentence:

> It is recognition of compassion’s part that leads the upholders of
>   capital punishment to accuse the abolitionists of sentimentality **in
>   being more sorry** for the murderer than for his victim.

My questions are:

1. Which one does "in being more sorry..." modify, "the abolitionists" or "sentimentality"? I would pick "the abolitionists."
2. Is it also fine to drop the preposition "**in**" before "**being more sorry**" as a state of being?

> It is recognition of compassion’s part that leads the upholders of
>   capital punishment to accuse the abolitionists of sentimentality 
>   **being more sorry** for the murderer than for his victim.

Answer (score 0):

Good (a.k.a. tough) question(s)!

1. I agree that the modification is to the abolitionists. One way to test that is to rearrange as something like:

> It is recognition of compassion’s part that leads the upholders of capital punishment to accuse the abolitionists, **in being more sorry for the murderer than for his victim**, of sentimentality.

2. Possible, but a bit risky. Dropping the “in” makes your first question even more relevant. I suspect most readers would still conclude that the meaning was as before, but I reckon omitting the “in” just dials up the dissonance a tad. That might be lessened by instead of simply removing the “in”, it were replaced,by a comma, but I still prefer the original form.